# Bootstrap sidebar link in list item take up whole button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the sidebar, which has a list of items and each item is a link to another page, I would like the whole rectangle of each item to be clickable, whereas right now you can only click on the link itself (so if you're hovering over or clicking the space next to the link, nothing happens).

```
<!-- sidebar -->
<div id="sidebar-col" class="col-sm-2">
  <div id="sidebar-div" class="affix-top" data-spy="affix">
    {% if math_problem_list %}
      <ul class="list-group">
      {% for math_problem in math_problem_list %}
        {% if math_problem.is_fully_answered %}
          <li class="list-group-item"><a href="{% url 'math_problem_blog_app:detail' math_problem.id %}">{{math_problem.title}}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    {% else %}
      <p>No fully answered math problems exist.</p>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.5 and making a Django app.

Answer (score 1):

The anchor element by default is an inline element.
So just add the following rules to your CSS to increase the clickable area of the anchor elements in your example.

```
.list-group-item {
  padding: 0;
}

.list-group-item a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
```